# Parsing .obj model from SD card Rajawali

Tags: android, opengl-es, rajawali

I am Working with Rajawali 3D Framework and trying to Load .obj files from SDcard. I am able to upload and parse the obj file when I put these files (.obj, .mtl, texture.png (drawable folder)) on raw folder but when I try to parse it from sdcard it says:

```
 [org.rajawali3d.materials.Material] Could not compile fragmentshader:
 Shader log: Fragment shader compilation failed.
```

Here is my code for uploading .obj files from Sdcard:

```
private Object3D Object;
LoaderOBJ objParser = new LoaderOBJ(this,"Load/1c_obj");

            try {

                objParser.parse();
                Object = objParser.getParsedObject();
                getCurrentScene().addChild(Object);

            } catch (ParsingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Logcat:**

```
 D/Rajawali﹕ Parsing: /storage/emulated/0/Load/1c_obj
 D/LoaderOBJ﹕ Found Material Lib: 1c_mtl
 D/LoaderOBJ$MaterialLib﹕ Parsing material: Texture0
 D/LoaderOBJ$MaterialLib﹕ Parsing material: Texture1
          
    9578-9612/com.example.loadobj D/LoadModelFragment$LoadModelRenderer﹕ startRendering()
    E/Rajawali﹕ [org.rajawali3d.materials.Material] Could not compile fragment shader:
    9578-9612/com.example.loadobj E/Rajawali﹕ Shader log: Fragment shader compilation failed.
    ERROR: 0:13: '.' : Syntax error:  syntax error
    ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your are able to read obj files from your raw folder which is

```
LoaderOBJ objParser = new LoaderOBJ(mContext.getResources(),mTextureManager, R.raw.camero_obj);
```

and not from your sdcard you have to do following changes in your files:
In your obj file that must be saved as **`_obj`** in your sdcard **(so for _jpg and _mtl in same location)**

in your case:

```
mtllib 1c_mtl

v -0.7526 14.5146 0.171602
v -0.7922 14.5792 0.075402
v -0.4998 14.7082 0.457802
v -0.5409 14.7486 0.393002
v -0.5358 14.5862 0.414902
```

Following by mtl file

```
newmtl Texture0
    illum 0
    Kd 0.7 0.7 0.7
    Ks 0 0 0
    Ka 0 0 0
newmtl Texture1
    illum 0
    Kd 0.7 0.7 0.7
    Ks 0 0 0
    Ka 0 0 0
    map_Kd parse_jpg
```

Remember to rename your texture jpg to **`_jpg`** 
Where you are getting Error:

> ERROR: 0:13: '.' : Syntax error:  syntax error

After this follow your code for parsing:

```
private Object3D Object;
LoaderOBJ objParser = new LoaderOBJ(this,"Load/1c_obj");

            try {

                objParser.parse();
                Object = objParser.getParsedObject();
                getCurrentScene().addChild(Object);

            } catch (ParsingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And The Error you are getting

> E/Rajawali﹕ [org.rajawali3d.materials.Material] Could not compile
>   fragment shader:

Its unable to read your texture file from your material file, For that you can do the above changes in your material file.

**For more details on custom material or vertex shader follow the Rajawail Document and sample**